# Can the answer highlighting animation be changed?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, meta

This is a special topic for the designer :P

[Is moderator voting anonymous?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-moderator-voting-anonymous/1456#1456)

The highlighting of the question is going from light yellow to white. It's not readable on SciFi as the background is dark, unlike other SE sites.

BTW, the overall design is very neat here! Good job!

Comment: [Related](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/989/new-design-launched#comment2050_994): a fix was made shortly after the design was launched; looks like the bad animation has crept back in.

Comment: +1 agreed, it looks weird.

Comment: Is this still a thing? Highlighting looks okay to me, but I haven't seen the site when it first went up so it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue in the current SciFi theme. Please let me know if the problem remains!