# Linking directly to post on this meta causes an orange-white fade, followed by dark grey snap

Tags: bug, design, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the answer highlighting animation be changed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/can-the-answer-highlighting-animation-be-changed)

Like other SE sites, directly linking to a post causes the post to be highlited in orange before fading away.

However, the fade effect is done by fading from orange to white.

Now image how this looks when you link to a post on this dark-background meta - the background fades from orange to white (same as text colour), and then suddenly turns dark. It doesn't look very good.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as this, right? http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/can-the-answer-highlighting-animation-be-changed

Comment: I guess it is, yeah. That never came up in the search for "has this been complained about already".